# Перечеркнутый текст по диагонали

Tags: html, css

Пробую трансформацией, но `transform-origin` приходится по пикселям подгонять, а если будет строка длиннее или короче, то все опять съезжает (должно быть по серединке).

**Вопрос:** Какие есть оптимальные варианты для верстки перечеркнутого текста по диагонали для строки разной длины?

```css
.str {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.str:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="str">Lorem ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что на чистом css есть что-то универсальное

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый просто способ , работает со любой разумной длиной

```css
p{
 white-space:pre;
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 font-size:20px;
}
p:after{
 content:"";
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;top:50%;
 color:red;
 width:100%;
 height:0;
 border-bottom:2px solid red;
 transform:rotate(-1deg);
}
```

```html
<p class="">Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.
</p>

<p class="">Praesent sapien massa,Praesent sapien massa,  convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.
</p>

<p class="">Praesent sapien massa, convallis 
</p>
```

Comment: Только сейчас подумал, что при перечеркивании таким способом коротких слов из 2-х 3-х букв наклона вообще не будет заметно, получится обычное горизонтальное зачеркивание.

Answer (score 4):

Могу предложить вот такой хак. Создается тег с классом, который обозначает зачеркивание. И в него скриптом добавляется svg зачеркивание. Тогда работает со строкой любой длины:

HTML:

```
<div>
SK tslk ser; k;stlk esl;kt <b class="trow">sdasfasfasfasfwshgf</b> srg ser se t
</div>
```

CSS

```
b{position:relative;}
svg{width:100%;position:absolute;height:100%;left:0;}
```

JS

```
$(".trow").append("<svg><line x1='0' y1='100%' x2='100%' y2='0' stroke-width='1' stroke='rgb(0,0,0)'></line></svg>");
```

Пример:

https://jsfiddle.net/v8vb6a8s/

Comment: спасибо, но не хотелось бы еще и скрипты на такое добавлять

Answer (score 0):

```css
.strikethrough {
  position: relative;
}
.strikethrough:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-color: inherit;

  -webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-5deg);
  transform:rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="strikethrough">Deleted text</span>
```

Comment: было же написано `для строки разной длины` ...... вот сделай свою строку длинней и ты почувствуешь боль...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну это более менее, по серединке. Лучше чем скрипты на такое сыпать.

Comment: @Elena но оно же, с учетом твоего же требования, бессмысленно.... и гуглится ровно минуту)  там и других решений достаточно.....однако при увеличении длины текста всегда беда.... мне кажется скрипт - is the only way.

Comment: вот добавила текст http://prntscr.com/f70jwn и линия по серединке,у меня проблема была в расположении. Мне ответ нравится, хотя не спорю что не идеален, но  ... и минусовать не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

вот вам самое простое решение

```
div{
  position: relative;
}
div::after{
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              left: 0;
              top:0;
              right: 0;
              bottom: 0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              background-image: url('../img/pages/product/old-price.svg');
              background-size: cover;
            }
```

суть такова что мы накладываем сверху псевдоэлемент с изображением подложки в формате svg. На нем нарисована линия по диагонали. Как бы вы не тянули вектор и не сжимали - пикселей как у jpg вы на нем не увидите, а линия будет четкой. Если вы не хотите заморачиваться с созданием файла - вы можете воспользоваться конструкцией

```
url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%"><line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0" stroke="#FF6969" stroke-width="2"/> </svg>');
```

но это будет работать не во всех браузерах как говорит [источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768451/inline-svg-in-css)

поэтому после перекодирования это строка будет выглядеть так

```
url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiPjxsaW5lIHgxPSIwIiB5MT0iMTAwJSIgeDI9IjEwMCUiIHkyPSIwIiBzdHJva2U9IiNGRjY5NjkiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMiIvPiA8L3N2Zz4=');
```

```css
.old-price{
          color: #9C9997;
          font-weight: 400;
          font-size: 16px;
          line-height: 140%;
          position: relative;
          }
         .old-price::after{
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top:0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiPjxsaW5lIHgxPSIwIiB5MT0iMTAwJSIgeDI9IjEwMCUiIHkyPSIwIiBzdHJva2U9IiNGRjY5NjkiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMiIvPiA8L3N2Zz4=');
            background-size: cover;
          }
```

```html
<span class="old-price">3200 р.</span>
```

Comment: @HamSter как тебе такое решение?